# Creating and passing byte data to socket in PHP based on code for C++

Tags: php, c++, sockets, unicode, pack

If that title didn't confuse you, I'll see what I can do here. I have the source of a C++ DLL that passes TCP traffic to a server. I believe all the relevant C++ code is below:

```
#define HRD_MSG_SANITY1     0x1234ABCD
#define HRD_MSG_SANITY2     0xABCD1234

typedef struct{
   unsigned int    nSize;
   unsigned int    nSanity1;
   unsigned int    nSanity2;
   unsigned int    nChecksum;
   WCHAR   szText[1];
} HRD_MSG_BLOCK;

CString strMessage = "this is a test\n";
 // I added this - the rest of the code
 // to determine this is unnecessary for
 // the context of this question.

//
//  Allocate.
//
int nMsgBytes  = sizeof(HRD_MSG_BLOCK) + sizeof(TCHAR) * (strMessage.GetLength() + 1);
HRD_MSG_BLOCK*  pMsgBlock  = (HRD_MSG_BLOCK*) new BYTE[nMsgBytes];
BYTE*           pMsgBuffer = (BYTE*)pMsgBlock;

ZeroMemory(pMsgBlock, nMsgBytes);

pMsgBlock->nSize     = nMsgBytes;
pMsgBlock->nSanity1  = HRD_MSG_SANITY1;
pMsgBlock->nSanity2  = HRD_MSG_SANITY2;
pMsgBlock->nChecksum = 0;

_tcscpy(pMsgBlock->szText, strMessage);

for (int nSendLoop = 0; (nSendLoop < MAX_SENDS) && (nToSend > 0); nSendLoop++) {
    //
    //  Send data to this port, max of 32k (0x8000).
    //
    int nSendSize  = min(nToSend, 0x8000);
    int nSentCount = (int)::send(g_socket, (char*)&pMsgBuffer[nSent], nSendSize, 0);

    //
    //  Error.
    //
    if (nSentCount == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        CSocketError error(::WSAGetLastError());

        //
        //  Report the error.
        //
        g_strLastError.Format(_T("Error sending %u bytes to socket %u - %s"),
                                      nSendSize,
                                      g_socket,
                                      error.Text());
    } else {
        nSent   += nSentCount;
        nToSend -= nSentCount;
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is accomplish the same thing via PHP. Here is the PHP code:

```
class HRD_MSG_BLOCK {
    public $nsize;
    public $nSanity1;
    public $nSanity2;
    public $nChecksum;
    public $szText;
}

$string = "this is a test\n";
$pMsgBlock = new HRD_MSG_BLOCK();
$nMsgBytes = 20 + (2*(strlen($string)+1));
 // I determined this by comparing to
 // actual size of TCHAR = 2 and actual
 // size of pMsgBlock = 20 in Visual Studio

$pMsgBlock->nSize = $nMsgBytes;
$pMsgBlock->nSanity1 = 0x1234ABCD;
$pMsgBlock->nSanity2 = 0xABCD1234;
$pMsgBlock->nChecksum = 0;
$pMsgBlock->szText = utf8_encode($string);
$binarydata = pack("C*", $pMsgBlock);
```

I then create the socket, and use `socket_write` to send `$binarydata`.

Obviously, I cannot use `pack()`, because I cannot convert a class object ($pMsgBlock) to an int (which is required as the second argument to pack()). I used utf8_encode() because the DLL documentation says:

> szText is the text being sent as a UNICODE (wide) string.

I'm having trouble determining exactly what the C++ DLL is sending to the socket so I'm basically guessing at what I need to send in PHP.

I could use help determining what the C++ code is sending exactly, and how I can do the same in PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: I should add that I do not have access to modify the receiving end, or even read the code. All I can do is look at the source code for the C++ DLL above (sending end) and try to send the same thing.

Comment: A wide string in Windows is UTF-16, not UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, so I can change utf8_encode($string) to mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-16"). However I still wont be able to pack the object to send over the socket like is done in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pack() a whole object, but you can pack() and concatenate the members. So, something like

```
$packed = pack('I', $pMsgBlock->nSize)
.pack('I', $pMsgBlock->nSanity1)
.pack('I', $pMsgBlock->nSanity2)
.pack('I', $pMsgBlock->nChecksum)
.mb_convert_encoding($pMsgBlock->szText, 'UTF-16');
```

Comment: Great! I think this is NEARLY what I am looking for.. This is the closest I've seen, but I'm not convinced the encoding for szText is correct just yet.. The server is still not recognizing the command. I'm certain that it's close here.. I did notice in the documentation "All requests and replies are terminated by hex 0x00. " so maybe I just need to add a \0 at the end, or another pack('I', 0);

Comment: Sure, append ."\0" if that's required. Odd to have both a size and termination, though.

Comment: Well, I'm finally getting a response back from the server, which means something is working. Unfortunately, the response is not what is expected, so I've got some more work to do. It looks like it's responding using the same format we sent in: passing the struct as binary data. I'll tinker with it some more, and try to determine whether or not the above was the correct way of sending the data. The response I'm getting back printed to console is "44." I'll have to wait until I get home to see if this is anything close to what I want to see, but I suspect it is not.

Comment: Mission success! I used netmon.exe to evaluate the incoming packets from the known good client and compared the incoming packets from the php script I'm working on. UTF-16 actually needed to be "UTF-16LE", and I had to do a bit of modification to the answer above to make it work, but we finally have success! Thanks Tino!