# C++/delphi socket TCP/IP to PHP - memcpy/move function in php

Tags: php, c++, sockets, tcp

I need to rewrite a example of sockets TCP/IP communication done in c++ or delphi(have this 2 examples) to PHP, but have a problem with function memcpy(c++)/move(delphi) and with the structures used in both languages.

**in both cases i have this 2 structures:** (struct from delphi)

```
SPMSifHdr = packed record
      ui32Synch1:       Longword;
      ui32Synch2:       Longword;
      ui16Version:      Word;
      ui32Cmd:          Longint;
      ui32BodySize:     Longint;
      end;

SPMSifRegisterMsg = packed record
      hdr1:             SPMSifHdr;
      szLicense:        Array[0..19] of char;
      szApplName:       Array[0..19] of char;
      nRet:             Longint;
      end;
```

**Code used to send message to server:**

```
procedure TForm1.btnRegisterClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  RegMsg: SPMSifRegisterMsg;
  byteMsg: Array[0..(sizeof(SPMSifRegisterMsg) - 1)] of byte;
begin
  FillChar(RegMsg, SizeOf(RegMsg), 0);
  SetHeader(CMD_REGISTER, RegMsg.hdr1);               //Set header information

  StrPCopy(RegMsg.szLicense, LicEdit.Text);           //build data to structure
  StrPCopy(RegMsg.szApplName, ApplEdit.Text);

  Move(RegMsg, byteMsg, sizeof(SPMSifRegisterMsg));   //copy structure to bytearray

  ClientSocket1.Socket.SendBuf(byteMsg, sizeof(SPMSifRegisterMsg));     //send the data
end;
```

**Problems:**

**1º - First in PHP how i can represent one structure like are used in c++ or delphi?**

Note: Remember i need pass this kind of structure in socket_send method, in 'buf' param)

**2º - In PHP what function do the same job like memcpy(c++)/move(delphi)?**

Note: For me it's not important put the information necessary to send directly to the memory block, but it's important convert the information to hex(?) like happens in c++ or delphi.

Structure with information before memcpy:

[image]

Result of memcpy function/information send to server:

[image]

I'm desperate with this situation, for second problem i've tried used the function "pack()" but i have no ideia what format to use, because i don't now what is the format they need to receive.

If necessary i can give more information.

**UPDATE:**

I think the right way to do the same job done in c++ or delphi in PHP is from this way:

```
$packed = pack('N', "1431655765")                   //HEADER - uint32 ui32Synch1
. pack('N', "2863311530")                           //HEADER - uint32 ui32Synch2
. pack('n', 1)                                      //HEADER - uint16 ui16Version
. pack('N', 1)                                      //HEADER - uint32 ui32Cmd;
. pack('N', "44")                                   //HEADER - uint32 ui32BodySize
. pack('C', "44436412") . pack('N', " ")            //BODY - char szLisence[20]
. pack('C', "Test_Program") . pack('N', " ")        //BODY - char szApplName[20]
. pack('I', 0);                                     //BODY - int  nRet
```

But i'm not sure because i don't know why debug this kind of communications. When i send the info with this method:

```
socket_send ( $sock , $message , 62, 0)
```

the script/page freeze on loading until give timeout and i don't receive any kind of message from server.

Someone can tell me if this is the right way to communicate in PHP? Or exist other ways to rewrite the code of c++ or delphi i've show?

**SOLVED:**

After some experiences i solve the situation doing only this:

```
  $message = pack('N', 1431655765)      //HEADER - uint32 ui32Synch1
. pack('N', 2863311530)                 //HEADER - uint32 ui32Synch1
. pack('v', 1)                          //HEADER - uint16 ui16Version
. pack('V', 1)                          //HEADER - uint32 ui32Cmd;
. pack('V', 44)                         //HEADER - uint32 ui32BodySize
. pack('a20', "44436412")               //BODY - char szLisence[20]
. pack('a20', "Test_Program")           //BODY - char szApplName[20]
. pack('I', 0);                         //BODY - int  nRet
```

Comment: PHP has absolutely NO concept of c-style structures. You have arrays and you have objects. That's it. There's no structs, no pointers, no memcpy/memmove type operations. PHP has absolutely **NO** memory management at that level.

Comment: Do **NOT** send whole structures over the wire like you're doing. Padding and endianness will bite you as soon as you run this on another platform than the one you developed and tested on. Serialize your data first (preferably as plain text so that humans can understand it too, not just computers) and deserialize it on the other end. I'm afraid your question is pointless, because you shouldn't even try this in the first place.

Comment: I am communicating with a system already exist, i can't change the way how the server receive the messages. That's the reason why put this 2 examples that already exist. After create this "question" i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588168/creating-and-passing-byte-data-to-socket-in-php-based-on-code-for-c. The way in PHP to "substitute" the structures is use function pack() concating each attribute of "structure"?